# Convert time zone abbreviations to full zone name?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a question regarding time zones. I have used the `moment tz` library so that I can get date offset based on timezone. For example, if I have the following code: `$scope.zoneName = moment.tz(new Date(), "America/New_York").format('z');` I understand that I can get an abbreviation of `EDT` or `EST` depending on if there is daylight savings or not. However, is there any way to get the full name of these time zones? I know there is the following here: http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/ where they say that they do not support long time zone names currently and it seems like a hassle to manually write down all ~384 time zone abbreviations, create some sort of key/value mapping like they did in the link above, and grab it that way. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard for time zone names, nor for their abbreviations. For example, in summer, Sydney Australia is in a zone formerly known as "Eastern Daylight Time", however that was often confused with the US EDT, so it is now more commonly called "Australian Eastern Daylight Time", but my browser calls it "E. Australia Daylight Time" and eBay calls it "AEDST", whatever that is. However, the [*IANA time zone names*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) have been widely adopted, so depending on your audience, they might be preferable. To be understood internationally, UTC offset is foolproof.

Comment: [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) has some of this information, but AFAIK there isn't a JS library ready to go that uses it.  Well, there are several CLDR libraries for JavaScript, but none that include the time zone localizations, that I am aware of.